# Arcs in jsxgraph

Tags: jsxgraph

I would like to create arcs in jsxgraph to indicate the angle between two lines. The documentation indicates this can be done with three points. However, is there some way to do this so that the arcs look like part of a circle, that is, given a centre point, a radius and start and end angles.

Of course, then I would like to be able to label the arc with the size of angle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JSXGraph has the `Angle` object which seems to do what you want. See https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Angle.html for examples.